# CSV document import by using filename statement

Tags: sas

I want to read a CSV document by using a `filename` statement in SAS but Excel already included variable names as the first line when I input variable names by using an `input` statement--there is going to be a mistake.  How can I deal with this situation?

```
filename outdata "C:\Users\Xiang\Desktop\crime2005.csv";

data crime;
    infile outdata dlm="," dsd ;
run;

proc means mean std maxdec=1 ;
run; 

proc print;
run;
```

Comment: Jimmy, I'm confused by your question, some formatting could help. Maybe you can print the first 4 lines from your CSV file. Are you simply saying your CSV is in the proper format (with a first row being variable names?) Have you looked up PROC IMPORT?

Answer (score 3):

First off - you're confusing things a bit by saying 'via the filename statement'.  This is via datastep.  The filename statement happens to be a relatively small component of this.

Second, let's get this into proper SAS indenting so we can see what's going on:

```
filename outdata "C:\Users\Xiang\Desktop\crime2005.csv";

data crime;
 infile outdata dlm="," dsd ;
 input [your-variable-list];
run;

proc means data=crime mean std maxdec=1 ;
run;

proc print data=crime;
run;
```

Data steps and Procs end with run (except for Procs that end in quit).  Each of these is a separate step, so always include the run.  Always include data= , unless you're using some fancy programming trick.  'data' always is in the first column, not indented - data step is the master statement, not filename.

These make your code readable, and protect you from mistakes.  Readable code is important, even if you work alone; it means you understand what you wrote five years ago, five years from now.

Your original question - how do I avoid the errors from the header row?

```
filename outdata "C:\Users\Xiang\Desktop\crime2005.csv";

data crime;
 infile outdata dlm="," dsd firstobs=2;
 input [your-variable-list];
run;
```

There you go.  FIRSTOBS=2 tells SAS to skip the first line [ie, the header row].

One thing you might try is a PROC IMPORT.  PROC IMPORT with DBMS=CSV will do something really handy for you - it will put in the log a complete data step with all of the code to read the file in yourself.  So while I don't actually recommend PROC IMPORT for production code [as it often makes poor decisions as to character/numeric formatting and lengths, among other things], it is very helpful to see how to get started with an input statement.

```
proc import file=outdata out=crime dbms=csv replace;
run;
```

Then look at your log, and copy that code out (removing line numbers); now you can modify it to your heart's content.